# Completion block not executed in a Singleton to access UIManagedDocument

Tags: ios, core-data, singleton

I am using the singleton pattern to access the unique UIManagedDocument accross my app. Everything works fine except that a completion block inside the singleton is never executed.

`ManagedDocumentHelper.m`:

```
+ (UIManagedDocument *) sharedDatabaseUsingBlock:(completion_block_t) completionBlock
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database"];

    static UIManagedDocument *managedDocument;
    static dispatch_once_t mngddoc;

    // synchronous
    dispatch_once(&mngddoc, ^{
        managedDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]){

            NSLog(@"Creating...");
            [managedDocument saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                NSLog(@"Created!");
                completionBlock(managedDocument);
            }];

        } else if(managedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){

            NSLog(@"Openning..."); //EXECUTED!
            [managedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                if(success){
                    NSLog(@"Open!"); //EXECUTED!
                    completionBlock(managedDocument); //NOT NIL
                }
            }];

        } else if(managedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
            completionBlock(managedDocument);
        }
    });

    return (UIManagedDocument *) managedDocument;
}
```

With `typedef void (^completion_block_t)(UIManagedDocument *document);`

Inside my controller:

```
@interface MyViewContoller()
{
    UIManagedDocument *_database;
}

@end


@implementation MyViewContoller

- (void) initializeDataBase
{
    if(!_database){
        _database = [ManagedDocumentHelper sharedDatabaseUsingBlock:^(UIManagedDocument *document){
            NSLog(@"DATABASE LOADED!! %@", document); // NEVER EXECUTED :(
        }];
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure completionBlock(managedDocument) gets called in all the cases? Did you try with breakpoints?

MySingleton.h

```
typedef void (^completion_block_t)(UIManagedDocument *document);

@interface MySingleton : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstanceWithCompletion:(completion_block_t)block;

@end
```

MySingleton.m

```
#import "MySingleton.h"

@implementation MySingleton

+ (instancetype)sharedInstanceWithCompletion:(completion_block_t)block
{
    static dispatch_once_t token;
    static MySingleton *instance;
    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        instance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    });
    block(nil);
    return instance;
}

@end
```

and wherever you want:

```
[MySingleton sharedInstanceWithCompletion:^(UIManagedDocument *document) {
    NSLog(@"Done");
}];
```

works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gets called in each case. I can see "Created!" (first time) and "Open!" the other times. However I never see "DATABASE LOADED!" (same behavior with breakpoints). Your example of the singleton always executes the block outside the queue which is slightly different to what I need (I need to execute after the `UIManagedDocument` has been correctly opened/created).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in a previous controller I was accessing the `UIManagedDocument` as well with the singleton and this created some kind of conflict with this access. Maybe the previous block was still in memory and this newer one was never called.